# How do I get new Database changes since last login using Django and Python?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to get database changes for a user, but only the updates of the user since the last time they logged in. I will be passing in just an email. I have looked into session data but none of that looks very helpful to me. I am new to Python and Django and I have no idea where to start, any help would be appreciated. Here are my models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
  serial = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False, unique=True)
  publickey = models.CharField(max_length=44, null=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return '%d: %s' % (self.id, self.serial)

class Pairing(models.Model):
  device = models.OneToOneField(Device,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=False, null=False)
  pairingcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return '%s: %s' % (self.device_id, self.pairingcode)

class UserDevice(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
null=False)
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  activation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
  friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
  is_owner = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
  is_alerts_enabled = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'device',)

  def __str__(self):
    return '%s => %s on %s' % (self.user.email, self.device.serial, 
  str(self.activation_date))

class Schedule(models.Model):
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  time = models.TimeField(null=False)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('device', 'time')

class PendingSchedule(models.Model):
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  time = models.TimeField(null=False)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('device', 'time')

class Tray(models.Model):
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  slot = models.IntegerField(null=False)
  full = models.BooleanField(null=False)
  time = models.DateTimeField(null=False)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('device', 'slot'), ('device', 'time'))

  def __str__(self):
    return 'Cup %s of %s %s' % (self.slot, str(self.device), "Full" if 
  self.full else "Empty")

class TrayStatus(models.Model):
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  slot = models.IntegerField(null=False)
  reason = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
  time = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
  recorded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
  expectedTime = models.DateTimeField(null=False)

class CheckIn(models.Model):
  device = models.OneToOneField(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  time = models.DateTimeField(null=False)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
  token = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
  first_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  last_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What does "database changes for a user" encompass?

Comment: Database changes would be anything for that user, eg .anything in TrayStatus, Tray, Schedule, UserDevice or Tray.

Comment: what about the signals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no `last_modified` fields on any of the relevant models, so start there:

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):
   # other fields...
   created = models.DateTimeField(autonow_add=True, db_index=True)
   last_modified = models.DateTimeField(autonow=True, db_index=True)
```

These will get filled automatically and don't appear in model forms (editable is forced to False). For each of the models you want to track for changes, you need to add the last_modified field and optional created field.

Now you can get the objects based on `User.last_login`:

```
# Get our user object based on email
user = User.objects.get(email=email)
# Get list of modified devices
modified_devices = UserDevice.objects.filter(last_modified__gte=user.last_login)
# ... and trays
modified_trays = Tray.objects.filter(last_modified__gte=user.last_login)
```

A Device will not change if a Tray linked to it is changed, so neither will the last_modified field of the Device.

The created field is for you to show the difference between modification and creation if you wish to do so:

```
new_devices = UserDevice.objects.filter(created__gte=user.last_login)
```

The challenge you face, if how to handle ownership changes of the device. You will probably need to keep track of that separately.

Comment: This kinda works but I just need what changed. eg. The Tray table will consists of 28 slots. if one slot is changed I don't need to get the whole tray back, just the one that changed.

Comment: The Tray model has one slot field. Linked to a device. So with "28 slots" you probably mean that for each device there will be 28 Tray model instances linked to it. So this will still work. I'll make the wording "Repeat for the rest of the models" more explicit.

Comment: Is there a way to get just the field that changed and not the whole row? eg. If friendly name changes for a user on UserDevice that is all I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

There are several third-party packages that allow you to do what you need, for instance [django audit log](https://django-audit-log.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [django reversion](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

You just need to pick the one that fits better your needs, both of them are very easy-to-integrate and use.